# Как можно с помощью JavaScript передать файл на сервер?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, node-redis

На счет картинки понятно - ее можно передать с помощью base64, а как файл?У меня файл 100 мб, я хочу положить его на сервер 192.168.1.1 в главний деректорий!

Answer (score 1):

для этого нам понадобится FormData

```
var formData = new FormData();
// добавляем файл
formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

отправляем аяксом

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your url here',
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, 
    processData: false, 
    // ... другие опции
});
```

замечание - файл обязательно нужно отправлять методом POST

Answer (score 1):

На чистом javascript это выглядит вот так:

Нужно создать [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData) и прикрепить к нему [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/File) или [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Blob):

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", document.querySelector('input').files[0]);
```

Отправить можно при помощи [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XmlHttpRequest):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/url");
xhr.send(formData);
```

Или при помощи [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
fetch("/url", {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
}).then(function (response) {
   ...
});
```

Как это сделать при помощи жуквери Вам уже ответили